# How to make JavaScript execute before page load?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have this code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function main(){
        function loadWordlist(url){
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 console.log('firstFunction');
              }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
          xhttp.send();
        }
        loadWordlist('https://www.example.com/');
      }
      main()
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log('secondFunction')
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Here i am getting the content from the url
And during that the browser contain loading the code and execute it

But i get `secondFunction` first then `firstFunction`
And i want `firstFunction` to execute first then `secondFunction` after `firstFunction` finish

Comment: Call the second function from the first function.

Comment: Just move `console.log('secondFunction')` to the same `if` block as `console.log('firstFunction')`.  Execute the "first" one, then execute the "second" one.  It's not really clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: That is not possible because i put the code in the head tag in the website i visit 
For interact with the website html content i did visit 
So I wanna load my function `main` first then contain execute or loading the website content

Comment: @abdallaEG: Why is it "not possible" to move the second `console.log` statement?  Or to wrap it in a function and invoke that function from your AJAX callback?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @David it's for testing but in real application it maybe a function or line of or html 
I don't know i want execute `main()` before anything 

But the browser runs main function and during that it execute or loading the website contain execute and loading the other content in this case `console.log('secondFunction')`

Comment: @abdallaEG: This sounds like more of a theoretical problem than an actual specific problem in specific code.  *In general*, when performing an asynchronous operation (such as an AJAX request), anything which needs to happen *after* that operation would be done in a callback (or potentially using `async` and `await` with Promises).  Currently there's nothing stopping you from doing that.  You're simply claiming that there *may* exist cases where you don't know how.  If you were to encounter such a case, that specific example may be an answerable Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the second function from the first function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function main(){
        function loadWordlist(url){
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 console.log('firstFunction');
                 secondFunction();
              }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
          xhttp.send();
        }
        loadWordlist('https://www.example.com/');
      }
      main()
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function secondFunction() {
        console.log('secondFunction');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

If that's not possible, you can make `xhttp.send()` blocking. I strongly advise against it. It's bad user experience. But it's possible, and maybe there are use-cases where this is the only solution.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function main(){
        function loadWordlist(url){
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 console.log('firstFunction');
              }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
          xhttp.send();
        }
        loadWordlist('https://www.example.com/');
      }
      main()
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log('secondFunction')
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: That is not possible because i put the code in the head tag in the website i visit For interact with the website html content i did visit So I wanna load my function main first and execute it then contain execute or loading the website content

Comment: @abdallaEG You can send a blocking, synchronous request https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open Why do you set `async = true` in `xhttp.open("GET", url, true);`

Comment: Note that a synchronous/blocking AJAX request is a *famously* bad idea (and may be deprecated by browsers over time, at the very least it should generate a warning currently).  Though it sounds like the OP *really wants* to do that anyway...

Comment: Thank you very much @jabaa
My bad 
I didn't know what this argument does so i set it to `true`